# Problem with juju bootstrap on an offline MAAS cluster, overlayroot does not exist?

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, offline

I am struggling to get Juju to successfully complete the bootstrap process on an offline MAAS cluster. I would really appreciate some help.

#### The Setup

- Hardware: Orange Box (cluster of 9 physical nodes and 2 virtual).
- Using MAAS v1.6
- Using Juju version 1.20.9
- Trusty

#### MAAS

All my nodes show as 'Ready' in the MAAS dashboard and they are powered off. The box is deliberately **not** connected to the internet.

Note that if I choose to 'start' a box through the MAAS dashboard it performs the power-up and trusty server image install without a problem.

#### Juju Problem

```
juju bootstrap --show-log
```

ends with a series of ssh attempts before failing with a timeout of 10 minutes. I *think* the problem is that when the chosen node is given a reboot command as part of the bootstrap, it remains powered up but does not boot successfully. This is based on running a ping command against the chosen box during bootstrap.

#### Possible cause is overlayroot?

I was able to ssh into the chosen node during one of the bootstrap attempt and capture (most of) cloud-init.log and cloud-init-output.log. They seem to suggest the problem might be something to do with 'overlayroot':

```
[WARNING]: Device 'overlayroot' did not exist. cannot resize: dev=overlayroot mnt_point=/ path=/
```

The full cloud init logs are at http://pastebin.com/L5FdZ7Qh and http://pastebin.com/gGD0Xe7c .

#### Note on Juju Tools

I created a local mirror of the juju 1.20.9 tools, used juju to generate the metadata and then set 'tools-metadata-url' in 'environments.yaml'.